# how to find time complexity of this code?

Tags: time-complexity

```
 sort(S);
 for i=0 to n-2 do
    a = S[i];
    start = i+1;
    end = n-1;
    while (start < end) do
       b = S[start]
       c = S[end];
       if (a+b+c == 0) then
          output a, b, c;
          start = start + 1;
          end = end - 1;
       else if (a+b+c > 0) then
          end = end - 1;
       else
          start = start + 1;
    end
 end
```

Here sort(S) sorts the given integers with time complexity O(n^2). How do I find the complexity of the above problem. Do we need any higher order mathematics to do this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the pseudocode by considering the worst case scenario.

```
 sort(S); # O(N log(N))

 for i=0 to n-2 do # O(N)

    start = i+1; # O(1)
    end = n-1; # O(1)

    while (start < end) # O(N - i)
       start = start + 1;  # O(1)
    end
 end
```

which can be also written as:

```
 sort(S); 

 for i=0 to n-2 do 
    for j = i+1 to n-1 do:
       ...
    end
 end
```

So the number of iterations is

```
1/2 N * (N+1) = O(N^2)
```

which is the dominant term with respect to the sorting function.

Comment: so if there are two different algorithms in a program then we compare their worst case complexity and then whichever is bigger the whole program has its worst case time complexity   right?

Comment: If they are run sequentially, as in this example, then yes. The algebraic rule is that O(f) + O(g) = either O(f) or O(g), whichever is larger.